# Gitignore file is ignored when uploading to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I want to push a NodeJs 'fullstack application to Heroku. That also works wonderfully. Only, it takes a very long time. I put a .gitignore file in the main directory, which is ignored when uploading.

[image]

This is how my gitignore looks:

```
 ### react ###
.DS_*
*.log
logs
**/*.backup.*
**/*.back.*

node_modules/*
bower_components

*.sublime*

psd
thumb
sketch
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have committed those files before adding gitignore, entries in gitignore will not affect. to fix you can remove those files and commit again. then gitignore will be available to ignore files